# i cant return all data from redis (redis-om and nextjs)

Tags: node.js, next.js, redis, node-redis

i have a app with blog,i used redis for database and redis-om for manage it , blog model in app it is :
class Blog extends Entity{}

```
const model_blog = new Schema(Blog,{
    title :  {type : "string"},
    description :  {type : "string"},
    body : {type : "text"},
    image : {type : "string"},
}, {
    dataStructure: 'JSON'
  })
```

i can insert data it but i can get all data from it
insert code :

```
const clinet = new Client()
const create_blog = async (data)=>{
    clinet.open('redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
    const blog_repository = clinet.fetchRepository(model_blog)
    const blog = await blog_repository.createAndSave(data)
    return blog
}
```

get all code :

```
const clinet = new Client()
const get_all_blogs = async ()=>{
    clinet.open('redis://127.0.0.1:6379')
    const blog_repository = clinet.fetchRepository(model_blog)
    const blog =await blog_repository.search().return.all()
    return blog
}
```

and this is text error :
`error - { name: 'Error', source: 'server', message: 'Blog:index: no such index' }`

I want to get all the Blog keys in my redis database when I call the get_all_blogs function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not creating an index for RediSearch to use. On the repository, you need to create an index by calling the aptly named `.createIndex`. ;)

```js
await blog_repository.createIndex()
```

Here's [the link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-om#build-the-index) for more details.

Also, you really only need to fetch the repository once. It is mildly more efficient to reuse it. And, as a bonus, you can call `.createIndex()` at the location where you create it as you certainly only want to call `.createIndex()` one time, when the application starts.